# I can not solve the error "coding classification not key value coding-compliant for the key"

Tags: ios, swift

It is a question.

This class is not key value code-compliant for the key error is given.

However, I am not sure which part is wrong. This error appears at cellForRowAt.

Thank you for your answer.

If you want it, I can also show the code of ContentTableViewCell, so please call out.

```
import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

var songs = [
    "裁量権を持って、若者向けカレンダーアプリ開発をしたいiOSエンジニア募集！",
    "自信を持って、応援出来るエンジニアを募集！"
]

var searchSongs = [String]()

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text!
    searchSongs = songs.filter {(name) -> Bool in
        return name.contains(searchString)
    }
    tableview.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    definesPresentationContext = true
    delegate()
}
}




extension searchViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if navigationItem.searchController?.isActive == true {
        return searchSongs.count
    } else {
        return songs.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContentTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ContentTableViewCell
    if navigationItem.searchController?.isActive == true {
        cell.commonInit(content: searchSongs[indexPath.row])
    } else {
        cell.commonInit(content: songs[indexPath.row])
    }
    return cell
}

func delegate() {
    tableview.delegate = self
    tableview.dataSource = self
    let nibName = UINib(nibName: "ContentTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    self.tableview.register(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ContentTableViewCell")
}
```

}

Comment: can you add the error

Comment: Probably your nib references an outlet that isn't in your cell subclass

Comment: [<UIImageView 0x7fcdda442df0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key .
(null)

objc[83878]: Attempt to use unknown class 0x600001b08e40.
105553154442304

It's the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in your Storyboard. I think any outlet is not connected properly. [image]

Check is there any yellow warning triangle in your storyboard on which screen this error is coming. If you found any, remove and connect the outlet again.

Comment: Good !! you did it.